# print statement not appearing in terminal

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm starting to play with scikit-learn after enjoying my AI class last semester. I have no prior experience with python (we used WEKA) so I set up python3 with a virtual env that has all the packages. I've activated the virtual env and try running the below code via `python3 <filename.py>`

from sklearn import svm, datasets
from numpy import genfromtxt, savetxt
import sys

```
def main():
    digits = datasets.load_digits()
    clf = svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100.)
    clf.fit(digits.data[:-1], digits.target[:-1])  
    SVC(C=100.0, cache_size=200, class_weight=None, coef0=0.0, degree=3,
    gamma=0.001, kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False,
    random_state=None, shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)
    print(clf.predict(digits.data[-1]))
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

which prints nothing to iterm (a mac os x bash terminal). So tried running this code

```
def main():
    print("hi", end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=True)
```

which also prints nothing. I've looked at the print documentation and asked a friend (who's only used 2.7) without figuring this out

Comment: Er, did you actually run the `main()` function?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does your main() function ever get called? Try adding this to the end of your module.

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: /facepalm. That's what I get for trying to jump straight into scikit without taking too much time to look at how python works. Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Did you actually *run* the `main()` function? In the above code you *defined* a procedure called `main()`, but it must be *called* to do something with it. Because you're working on a terminal, simply type `main()` and press `[ENTER]`.

If you were running the program from a file, then @AndrewJohnson's answer is spot-on.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with several types of python script. Just corrected it by checking the indentation. Correct indentation.